# Error in merge statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have this my stored procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[Sp_AddPermission]
@id nvarchar(max)
as
    declare @words varchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @words = @id

    set @sql = 'merge admin AS target
    using (values (''' + replace(replace(@words,';','),('''),'-',''',') + ')) AS source(uname, [add], [edit], [delete], [view],Block)
on target.uname = source.uname
when matched then update set [add] = source.[add], [edit] = source.[edit], [delete] = source.[delete], [view] = source.[view], [Block]=source.[Block];'

    exec(@sql);
```

When executing it, this error is shown:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

How to resolve this?

Regards

Baiju

Comment: Make sure that the values in `source` are unique.

Comment: Did you try googling

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is obvious:  you a generating a source table with multiple values for the same `uname`.

Why are you using a `merge` for this?  I think a simple update would do, and I don't think `update` will return an error when you have multiple identical keys in `source`:

```
update t
    set [add] = source.[add],
        [edit] = source.[edit],
        [delete] = source.[delete],
        [view] = source.[view],
        [Block]=source.[Block]
    from target t join
         (values(. . . )) s(uname, [add], [edit], [delete], [view],Block)
         on t.uname = s.uname;
```

But, you could fix this if you like by choosing an arbitrary row for the update (which is what the above does):

```
update t
    set [add] = source.[add],
        [edit] = source.[edit],
        [delete] = source.[delete],
        [view] = source.[view],
        [Block]=source.[Block]
    from target t join
         (select s.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by uname order by uname) as seqnum
          from (values(. . . )) s(uname, [add], [edit], [delete], [view],Block)
         ) s
         on t.uname = s.uname and s.seqnum = 1;
```

Of course, this approach can also be used with the `merge`.